# Pandas: shift one column until other column value = True

Tags: pandas, dataframe, shift

I have a dataframe like this one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'date': ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02','2021-01-03','2021-01-04'],
    'order': [False, False, True, True]
})
```

And I want to have a new column with the shifted date from the column with the next order = True. So the dataframe would look like this:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'date': ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02','2021-01-03','2021-01-04'],
    'order': [False, False, True, True],
    'shifted_date': ['2021-01-03','2021-01-03','2021-01-04',np.nan]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the True values with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shere.html), fill backwards with [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html), and [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df['shifter_date'] = df['date'].where(df['order']).bfill().shift(-1)
```

output:

```
         date  order shifter_date
0  2021-01-01  False   2021-01-03
1  2021-01-02  False   2021-01-03
2  2021-01-03   True   2021-01-04
3  2021-01-04   True          NaN
```

Comment: Could you help me with finding the correct solution when I want to apply this to groups of the df? Eg. if I have a 4th column with 'a' or 'b' and I want to apply it to every group (a,b) seperatly.

Comment: Then apply the `bfill` per group: `df['date'].where(df['order']).groupby(df['group']).apply(lambda s: s.bfill().shift(-1))`

Comment: And if I would like to group by 2 columns? df['date'].where(df['order']).groupby(df['group','group2']).apply(lambda s: s.bfill().shift(-1)) is not working for me

Comment: `groupby([df['group'],df['group2']])` you need to do some research, this is covered in many Q/A ;)